# Responsive Angular 2 web-app to mobile app

Tags: android, angular, apk, responsive

I have a responsive angular 2 wep-app that behaves like a mobile app when the screen resolution is reduced.  Are there any tools that can convert the web-app to an apk mobile app?

Also, I was wondering if there's a mobile app template/project available online that works like a web browser but it can only navigate to one website?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a few ways you can do it . For myself , i created my web-app using ionic Framework . The language i used is in angular2 & typescript.
But the downfall for these, you might be needing some knoweledge on how ionic works.

**BUT**

Aside from that , the other easier way to do it is to use apache cordova to convert your web-app to apk mobile app. 
Follow these steps @ https://auth0.com/blog/converting-your-web-app-to-mobile/ and you do just fine.

Another thing to take note of , 
If you want to test your apk in an emulator , Dont use sdk emulator as it really slows down your laptop/desktop. Use GenyMotion instead.

You have to register and its free, it saves alot of time and run smoother . All you do is drag your apk file to genymotion.

Do also note that you will be needing Virtual Machine for your genymotion. 
I hope with this, it will help you with coverting your web-app to mobile-app

Cheers :)